# How to automatically deploy Function App contents using Resource Group project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, webdeploy, azure-rm-template

There are very good instructions on how to automate Web App deployment - both creating the required infrastructure and deploying the web app contents.
For example, this is very well described [here](https://github.com/rgl/azure-content/blob/master/articles/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy.md)

However, I can't find any detailed instructions on how this is done for a Function App.

What is my case:

- I'm using Azure RM Template deployments with a Visual Studio 2017 Resource Group project
- I have successfully defined the Function Template
- I have successfully defined the Web Deploy Template for the function
- I have created my Function as a separate project and it is working correctly
- On the Resource Group project, a reference to the Function project has been added and its properties defined as follows:
  [image]

When I deploy the Resource Group it fails with the message **"The target "Package" does not exist in the project."**

This means that it cannot build the ZIP package.

Everything is working fine if I remove the "Package" parameter from "Include Targets" and then manually supply the "package.zip" to the Resource Group project.

**How should the Resource Group project be configured in order to be able to self-build the ZIP package for the Function App project?**

**Is it possible to add a "Package" target in the Function app project?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround which actually is quite elegant and pretty simple. 
Hopefully, this will help others:
    1. Install ["MSBuildTasks" NuGet package](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) on the Function App project
    2. Open to edit the .csproj file of the Function App project and add the following somewhere within the `<Project>` element:

```
<Project>
  ...
  <Import Project="$(ProjectDir)obj\FunctionApp.csproj.nuget.g.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectFiles Include="$(OutDir)\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Package">
    <Zip Files="@(ProjectFiles)" WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" ZipFileName="$(PackageLocation)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

3. The important parts in the upper snippet are the following. They help bind the Target to the Resource Group project (see the image in the Question):

   - the name of the `Target` should be "Package", which is called by the Resource Group Project
   - the usage of the `$(PackageLocation)` property which is passed by the Resource Group Project

[This blog post helped me.](http://%20https://peteris.rocks/blog/creating-release-zip-archive-with-msbuild/)

Comment: thank you very much. was beating my head on wall for this one.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll put yourself in a much better position if you embrace Azure Devops up front and automate this process using a CI/CD pipeline.

I’ve done a number of these in the past by breaking up the deployment into three steps (my projects tend to have a logic app which calls the function):

1. Have an ARM template which contains all the resource group contents other than the logic app. Deploy it first using a [resource group deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=vsts)
2. Use an [app service deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=vsts) to publish the zip file generated during the build process. This creates the function app endpoint which would need to exist before the logic app can be deployed
3. Deploy the logic app from a separate ARM template using another resource group deployment step

I know the logic app piece is outside of the scope you’ve defined in your question, so in your case you’d just leave out the third step.

Even with just a simple function app deployment I’d still make the argument that having a CI/CD pipeline will make your life easier in the long run.

[Kloud blog just added a great write up of how to do this](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/10/17/step-by-step-using-azure-devops-services-to-deploy-arm-templates-with-ci-cd-part-1/).

Comment: interesting things mentioned, thanks. Sure, this gives another perspective, however I'm not able to migrate our company projects in this way at this stage. My main concern is generating the ZIP and passing it to the Resource Group project. I'm on a path of discovering a workaround. As soon as I'm ready, I will post another answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Building on Vladislav's very help full answer...

A bug in MSBuildTasks nuget deployment prevents it from installing as documented at the project site for .Net Core projects. The .build folder never gets created.

If you add MSBuildTasks, version 1.4.0.128 to a .Net Framework project in the solution, you can use the Import as described on the site:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)\.build</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
```